# ASP.NET/Entity - Method Group Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to take all the gathered information and build them into an array in case it contains more than one address with the same address type.

```
var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c).ToString().ToArray;
```

However, `gathered` gives me this error when I hover over it:

> Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

I have tried to research the issue but cannot seem to identify why this is not working, can anyone possibly take a look at it for me?

Comment: ToArray is a method, so `ToArray()`. And `ToString()` before it does not make much sense, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: You are missing a set of parentheses at the end of ToArray.  You are assigning the method call ToArray to your var, rather than the result of calling it.

Comment: Well, some of the entries contain more than 1 address to the same address type. IE: address type 3 with the businessID of 3LE has 3 addresses corresponding to it. Therefore, I need to pull out all of the addresses rather than just the `FirstorDefault()`. @Andrei

Comment: Thank-you @Paddy, adding `()` actually fixed that error. If you make an answer, Ill mark it.

Comment: @KyleE4K, then just use `ToArray()`, `ToString()` is used for something entirely different

Comment: I removed the `ToString()` and that fixed my second issue, thankyou @Andrei